# H.265 playback. CPU usage: 385%

Tags: video, pi-3b+

Brand new Raspberry Pi model B+ with heavy cooling system.

Trying to play a 1920x1080p h.265 video.
VLC/ffplay shows 1 frame/minute, impossible to watch.
CPU usage is reported 385.5% by `top`.

Is it possible to play h.265 videos on RPi 3B+?

Comment: since h.265 video is not handled by the GPU, it must be decoded by the CPU - obviously you know this ... latest 2B, 3B or 3B+ (they all use the same CPU these days) *may* be able to decode it well enough, but you won't know until you try with that specific video - i.e. I can watch some h.265 videos, but not all

Comment: Please don't use images, instead paste the text output into the question.

Comment: What if I want to attach the image? Is it bothering you? Is it agains the rules? Please don't make useless comments.

Comment: It's on you if you like to get help for free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Core #   Max %
  1      100
  2      100
  3      100
  4      100
Total    400
```

The line at the top of `top` is amalgamated -- i.e., it is an average of the 4 cores.  But the individual process lines show percentage of one core, which will be greater than 100% if they are making use of such.

Comment: Good point. I wonder if there is a way to update the h.265 codecs. Full HD h264 videos play so smooth on this device!

Comment: `Raspberry Pi 3 does not have H.265 decoding hardware` Quote from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi . H.264 is supported by the hardware while H.265 not.

Comment: dang it and I wanted to get more than 100% usage out of a CPU....

Comment: @GramThanos you should make that an answer instead of a comment on another answer.

Comment: @GramThanos Seems perfectly clear to me: OP wants to know if H.265 playback is supposed to work, finds that it doesn't work to his expectations, and has troubleshot that the CPU usage is ridiculously high.  But English is my native language, so that might have something to do with it.