# HEVC playback on RPi 4

Tags: video, pi-4

Raspberry Pi 4 lists HEVC (H.265) video decoding up to 4K@60fps in the [spec](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-4-model-b/specifications/). I'd like to get some feedback from people who already had a chance to try it out.

- Is this hardware or software encoding?
- Does it support the 10-bit profiles?
- Does it work in common Linux media players which can be installed from the Debian repo (like `vlc` or `mpv`), or does a special RPi-only build have to be used?
- Does it require a license, similar to MPEG-2 on older RPi?

Comment: When listed in the specs it is hardware capability.  Whether the software exists that can talk properly to the hardware, is another matter.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I'm inclined to think that too, considering that HEVC brings an RPi 3+ [to its knees](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/93495/33476), and RPi 4 is not *that* different CPU-wise. I'd actually like to see a confirmation that it really works on RPi 4.

Comment: Related: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/104939/pi-4-can-it-play-blu-ray-rips

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- It is a hardware *decoder*.<sup>[1](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=243541#p1485086)</sup> <sup>[2](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=243372&start=50#p1484079)</sup> No hardware encoder is present.
- Yes. <sup>[2](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=243372&start=50#p1484079)</sup>
- No, as of 17-July-2019 the necessary patches are not in upstream, but exist as an downstream fork of ffmpeg. <sup>[3](https://github.com/popcornmix/FFmpeg/tree/2711)</sup> LibreELEC ("Just enough OS for Kodi") uses it already.
- No, the cost is included in the price already.

Comment: Is there official ffmpeg support yet for HVEC on the rpi4?