# Pi 4: Can it play blu ray rips

Tags: video, streaming-video, pi-4

So basically I couldn't find an answer to this directly. But can a Pi 4 blu ray play blu ray rips(from my own blu rays) without issues? With the pi 3 and older, it was too much. Is the pi 4 powerful enough?

Thanks in advance,

Bunsen

Comment: Should be able to, try LibreELEC https://libreelec.tv

Comment: Try it, you won't break anything.

Comment: Depends on what player you use. `omxplayer` is capable of playing 1080p with no significant CPU usage. But RPi 4 is not supported yet.

Comment: @Dougie, I can't try it if I do not have it yet ;)
others thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be enough, but the performance will depend on the codec used:

- HEVC, H.265 and H.264 are supported in hardware, so those will offer the best performance with a compatible video player such as VLC.
- Older formats such as MPEG-2 are decoded in software, which is fine in most cases. Videos with high bitrates (such as Blu-ray) will result in significant CPU load though.

Early Blu-ray disks use MPEG-2 codec natively, so the playback of such  raw BD rips (`.M2TS` files) on the RPi 4 will rely on a software codec. More recent Blu-ray (`.M2TS`) and [AVCHD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVCHD) rips (`.MTS` files, DVDs for Blu-ray players) use H.264 and will be decoded in hardware on an RPi 4.

If your rips are transcoded (so you have made `.AVI`/`.MKV`/`.MP4` files instead of `.MTS`/`.M2TS`), the original codec is not important. Be sure to pick one of the hardware-supported codecs when transcoding.

Note that if you need post-processing during playback (e.g. playing a 3D Blu-ray as 2D on a regular screen), hardware decoding will not work regardless of the codec (at least in VLC). Playing a full HD 3D H.264 stream in 2D with software decoding is about as much as an RPi 4 can handle, that is, the playback is not always smooth and there is some frame drop.

Comment: Thanks, that is the answer I needed.

Comment: "Blu-ray disks use MPEG-2 codec natively" - this is not quite correct. Only very early Blu-Ray releases used. Most blu-rays use H264. Furthermore, your assumption that .m2ts always contains MPEG-2 is incorrect; it can contain H264 streams too (and in fact, in my experience this is the most common format). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blu-ray https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.m2ts

Answer (score 0):

Of course Pi4 can play a bluRip file. But you have to notice 2 things:
1. Do not keep open other processes while playing videos
2. Use a good HDMI cable and a good power source

Comment: You mean play it fine, or play it like it does on pi 3?

Comment: I tried some videos on pi4. AVI formatted files doesn't work very well. But MKV format is ffine. MP4 too

Comment: Those are blu ray rips? I have a pi2 and a pi3 as media centre, and both do not like blu rays, the rest of the files are not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is very good question, on rpi 1-2-3 i use special license keys to unlock hardware ecoding MPEG-2 and VC-1. But on rpi4 hardware decoding of MPEG-2 and VC-1 not supported.
http://www.raspberrypi.com/mpeg-2-license-key/
http://www.raspberrypi.com/vc-1-license-key/

Comment: Since the poster specifically stated they have a Pi 4, why post an answer which applies to anything but Pi 4?