# Recoding video files for easy (low CPU) playback on Pi4 / Firefox

Tags: pi-4, video, gpu

I won't go into the full detail of how we arrived here but I have a need to play two (locally stored on the eMMC) video files simultaneously in Firefox running on a Pi CM4.

Right now it's struggling for a variety of reasons (mainly because the files are full HD being squashed to fit in the page) - I'm planning on re-encoding & scaling the videos with `ffmpeg` to remove as much CPU/GPU load from the Pi as possible.

With that in mind I have the following questions;

1. What's the optimum format / parameters (EG bitrate) that will reduce the processing load on the Pi when playing back? We have plenty of storage and can take as long as we need to do the re-encoding.
2. Are there any settings/confg to check in Raspbian / Firefox to ensure the GPU is being used to full effect?

Comment: @JohnU True, but you still might want to explain why you want to play videos with a browser instead of a regular video player.

Comment: Regarding video formats, check out https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/104939/33476

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev - the requirement isn't "just play videos on a CM4" because obviously you use a video player for that, the requirement is "play videos as part of an interactive web page in firefox" but I hoped that I didn't need to give an entire back-story in the question just to head off stereotypical SO pedantry.

Comment: @Milliways - I just checked, Chromium is way slower and can't play the videos smoothly, even re-scaled and re-compressed. What's your far better solution you're not sharing?

Comment: All I was pointing out was that Firefox doesn't use Pi hardware acceleration which is what you asked.

Comment: @JohnU I wish we could skip the pedantry, but people keep coming here asking how to kill a fly with a cannonball, and many are relieved to learn there is a flyswatter for that. How do I know upfront you're not that kind of user?

Comment: Anyhow, if you say Chromium is way slower than Firefox, I wonder which OS you have, which version of browsers, what are your relevant settings (`gfx.webrender` in Firefox? the output of `chrome://gpu` in Chromium?). On my system it's the other way around: Chromium is faster.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev - completey normal unmodified Raspbian, latest build downloaded from the official website, likewise default installations of Firefox & Chromium.
Also I thought my question was fairly clear that the requirement was to use the browser (suggesting that I knew other means of video playback were available and that this requirement was arrived at due to other constraints/requirements) but whatever -  none of this is getting us closer to an answer.